# The method is() is undefined for the type in UnitTest Controller with Mockito

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

i'm newbie with the Spring boot. And the UnitTest with Controller drive me crazy
I have file pom.xml like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nashtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBikeShop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyBikeShop</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Junit 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mockito extention -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And when i make a ControllerTest, it can define method is

[image: Error got like this]

I tried to import as many as i can find but it still not work. I had delete spring-boot-test-autoconfigure folder but still nothing

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `is()` method for it to be available for use in your class, add at the top of your file:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
```

You might alos need to add [Hamcrest Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core) to your Maven dependency list.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
  <version>todo.x.y.z</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful way to did it

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.size()", Matchers.is(listOrder.size())));
```

But when i perfom like this:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/order")
            .content(ow.writeValueAsString(orderEntity))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).andReturn();
result.getResponse().getContentAsString()
```

is a empty String. I dont know why